# 中{なか} vs 中{ちゅう}

Tags: word-choice, kanji

When to read a character as 中{なか}, and when to read it as 中{ちゅう}?

Comment: As far as I know 中{なか} means 'within' and 中{ちゅう} 'all over'.
Can you tell us a specific situation in which you don't know which to use?

Comment: @user2740 I just see the Chinese charactors frequently and not sure know how to pronounce.

Comment: You should really put that in the question! It seems currently as if you want to formulate a sentence. But you actually want to know how to guess the meaning.

Comment: @user2740 Ok, I will make my question more easier to understand in future, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「中」（ちゅう） is an 音読み (*onyomi*) so it is [used in multi-*kanji* compound words and words that do not end in *hiragana*](http://www.tofugu.com/2010/03/23/the-types-of-kanji-in-japanese-onyomi-vs-kunyomi/) （途中 [*tochuu*], 午前中 [*gozenchuu*], 中心 [*chuushin*], 中途半端 [*chuutohanpa*]）.

「中」（なか） can be a stand-alone word in a sentence. However, it can also be used in combinations （仲良し [*nakayoshi*], 仲直り [*nakanaori*], 真夜中 [*mayonaka*]), place names （中野区 [Nakano-*ku*], 中川区 [Nakagawa-*ku*]), and surnames （田中 [Tanaka], 中西 [Nakanishi]), etc.

If you are in a situation where you need to guess on the pronunciation in a multi-*kanji* compound word, guess なか if it is the first *kanji* in the word and guess ちゅう if it is the last *kanji* in the word.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, sorry for that. But I think that 中{なか} can be used by itself. For example: 猫{ねこ}は部屋{へや}の中{なか}にいます。 - Cat is in a room. (lit. Cat exists in a room.)
Whereas 中{ちゅう} can't be used by itself but must be a part of a word. For example: 中{ちゅう}学{がく}生{せい} - Middle school student.

I think that's it. By the way: 中{なか} is kun-reading, and 中{ちゅう} - on-reading. Kun-readings are mostly used by themselves but on-readings, in most cases, are part of a word(s).