# Is it 散歩中【さんぽちゅう】には or 散歩中【さんぽなか】には?

Tags: readings, parsing, multiple-readings

> 雨【あめ】が降【ふ】ったり、途中【とちゅう】でけがをする子【こ】がいたり、途中【とちゅう】でけんかが始【はじ】まったり……散歩中【さんぽちゅう】には、さまざまなアクシデントが起【お】こりえます

> *It may rain, a child may get injured on the way, or a fight may break out on the way. ...... Various accidents may occur during a walk.*

[source](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASQ2L3QJRQ2KULEI00G.html?iref=comtop_Edu_01)

Comment: Related/Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24973/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 散歩[中]{ちゅう}, just like 作業[中]{ちゅう} and 移動[中]{ちゅう}.